# Win 10 : Is there any way to give my user account FULL admin rights? Not make it an administrator account

Tags: windows-10, permissions, user-accounts, administrator

By default, a new installation of win 10 creates an account with administrator rights (belongs to the administrator group). The problem is that windows will still keep prompting me to provide admin rights for a TON of stuff, like renaming a drive. Clicking "yes" to provide that permission does not actually work...it just endlessly prompts me to provide admin permission infinitely.

I know how to enable the hidden administrator account in lusrmgr, that is not the problem.

**What i am asking is whether i can somehow give my regular account called "Question" FULL admin rights exactly like the hidden administrator account.** This account is already in the administrator group but that is insufficient...windows keeps prompting me infinitely for admin permission.

I have more than 13gb of files in my "Question" documents folder and my understanding is that this will be lost if i swap to the hidden administrator account so i want to give this account the full rights, instead of swapping to the hidden admin account.

I have done searches and all i can find is "use the hidden administrator account", which is what im trying to avoid.

This is not a UAC problem. Please do not recommend disabling UAC as that will not solve it.

This is window keeps complaining that i need administrator rights even though i am part of the administrator group. This is an internal 3.5 inch seagate barracuda drive.

[image]

Comment: On Windows an Administration account is an Administrator at least from a permission perspective. You can disable UAC on the system but on modern versions of Windows this will break things like UWP applications. There is no such thing as a “full administrator account” an account is either an Administrator or it’s not.

Comment: @Ramhound Then why does it keep complaining that i need to provide administrator permissions when i am already an administrator? And clicking "yes" does not work, it just keeps prompting me infinitely for administrator permissions.

Comment: Care to provide a screenshot?  I suspect ownership is the problem not permission problem. Also provide a screenshot of the properties of the file showing the permissions for all Administrators would be helpful. I have a specific train of thought that can provide a detailed answer provided I understand exactly the situation with your system

Comment: Even an Administrator account will show the UAC prompts asking if you want to USE the Administrator rights. The difference is that when using a non-admin account you'll be promoted to enter the Administrator account's credentials, and when logged in to the Administrator account you'll just be prompted for yes/no whether you wish to use the rights.

Comment: @Ramhound : https://i.imgur.com/os4qvPG.png

Comment: @music2myear : https://i.imgur.com/os4qvPG.png

Comment: im a member of the administrators group, which has full control over the drive, yet i keep getting asked to provide administrator permission. This makes no sense. Its not even the standard UAC screen and disabling UAC has no effect (i tried).

Comment: By default the permissions of an external drive unless it’s another Windows partition, should have permissions that allow, any user from any Windows installation access to the drive. “This makes no sense. It’s not even the standard UAC screen and disabling UAC has no effect (i tried).” - It’s not UAC, that dialogue, is literally saying you have no permissions. You should add the image to your question. Additionally, understanding more about the drive, might provide helpful insight into what’s actually happening

Comment: @Ramhound : This is an internal drive, not an external one. Its a 3.5 inch seagate barracuda drive. But the security tab says administrators have full control and i am part of the administrators group? I dont get it.

Comment: @Question - When I refer to external disk I mean any disk that isn’t the system disk. Have you by chance moved your user profile to this disk?

Comment: @Ramhound : No, widnows is on the SSD, not the HDD. Why does it say administrators have full control when clearly, they do not?

Comment: @Question - NTFS file system problem, I would backup the data with the built-in Administrator account which does work, then format the drive. The permissions on the disk should allow any user access to the files even if they were not an Administrator the ACL suggests otherwise

Answer (score 1):

I've got a feeling this has NOTHING to do with being an Administrator or not.

It sounds as if the NTFS permissions on that specific drive got somehow seriously messed up.

You may be able to re-apply the permissions for all files/folders to "Administrators" "Full Control", alternating with "Take Ownership" if you can't re-apply the rights. (Will probably have to be done multiple times to get all files/folders covered.) But that is a major hassle and doesn't guarantee that it will fix the problem.

The only sure solution to this is to move all your files of that drive to another medium and then re-format it.

Answer (score 0):

> What i am asking is whether i can somehow give my regular account
> called "Question" FULL admin rights exactly like the hidden
> administrator account.

Yes and no.

Yes, you can make yourself Administrator in Users and Groups or in Account Settings.

You really should NOT enable the built in Administrators Account. That is a serious security risk. Anybody who gets access can use it.

Yes, you can set UAC to the second highest level of security. Then you just need to press OK but you do not need to enter credentials.

So then No, you cannot (in any practical way) give your regular Admin Account more freedom without disabling UAC, which is also not a good idea.

Regular Admin plus second highest UAC level is a very easy way to operate.

Also make sure you have proper ownership of the files you are trying to manage

> This is a freshly built PC and a fresh installation of windows

You may wish to back up this machine, and reinstall Windows. Put some files back temporarily and test file permissions before installing software.

Make sure your Windows install is a standard, complete, Windows 10 installation.

You should get the manufacturer's test for your main drive and test that for errors before re-installing Windows.

Comment: The problem is that windows floods me with "you need to provide administrator permissions" when i try to do things like rename a disk volume. Clicking "yes" does not work, it just prompts me to provide permission again.

Comment: Check if your OS is working properly.  Set up as I describe, I am not flooded with permission requests

Comment: Also you have full ownership (not to be confused with being Admin) of your files so Windows does not stop you.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/os4qvPG.png, im a member of the administrators group, which has full control over the drive, yet i keep getting asked to provide administrator permission. This makes no sense. Its not even the standard UAC screen and disabling UAC has no effect (i tried).

Comment: You might wish to repair your OS.  I do not get this kind of issue - any of my computers

Comment: This is a freshly built PC and a fresh installation of windows...

Comment: I do not know what is wrong with it but this is an issue I have not seen. Me or customers

Comment: I suggested a method of Windows reinstall that should help you

Comment: The reinstalling of Windows on a different disk then the disk in the author’s screenshot seems like an overkill solution. I suspect this is a plain old NTFS ownership issue

Comment: I do not see why (from what I have read) that the issue is an NTFS ownership issue. I suggested ownership before. Windows (installed correctly) uses standard NTFS file systems and I have not seen this issue before - here or customers.